# sudo lightdm stop causes low-graphics mode

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, lightdm

I'm trying to install the CUDA drivers for Nvidia GPU on ubuntu 16.04. In order to do this I need to kill server-X by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F1 and run

```
sudo lightdm stop
```

The first time I did this it worked normally. However I don't know if I messed with something buggy or what related to the graphics driver, everytime I run this in TTY mode I get the same error as in [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). The only difference is that when I reboot things are back to normal.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this, such as a reparing/update of some sort? I'm also considering completally reseting Ubuntu.

Honestly after hours trying to figure this out just to installing a simple drive I'm very upset. I don't understand why Ubuntu has to be so freaking complicated.

Comment: Why don't you boot to non-graphics mode and then install the graphics drivers after which you can start lightdm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there was a `service` keyword missing. The correct would be:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

So it stops the graphical OS without "complaining" that the graphical interface stoped.